# How to make Google Charts responsive with navigation tabs

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I have been able to make my Google charts responsive to browser window resizing with the following code:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.TreeMap(
    document.getElementById('stuEnrCDTree')
);
chart.draw(data,options);

function resizeHandler () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
}
```

However, my page includes a tab menu at the top which allows the user to see groups of Google charts based on categories. When the user selects a different tab, the charts do not resize - resizing is only accomplished when the window is resized.

Is there a particular function or option that will resize the charts when the user selects another tab? Here is a [link to the page in question](http://www.uh.edu/ir/) (click on the "Student Demographics" tab after the main page loads for an illustration). Here are the specifications for one chart on the page:

```
function drawChartstuEnrCDTree() {
    var data = gvisDatastuEnrCDTree();
    var options = {};
    //options["width"] = [1100];
    options["height"] = [500];
    options["minColor"] = ["#d7191c"];
    options["midColor"] = ["#ffffbf"];
    options["maxColor"] = ["#1a9641"];
    options["fontColor"] = ["black"];
    options["title"] = ["Change in College & Department Enrollment, Fall 2011 to     2015 (right click graphic to return to college level; red [-] green [+])*"];
    options["showScale"] = [true];
    options["showTooltips"] = [true];


    var chart = new google.visualization.TreeMap(
        document.getElementById('stuEnrCDTree')
    );
    chart.draw(data,options);

    function resizeHandler () {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeHandler);
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="chart" id="stuEnrCDTree"></div>
</div>
```

Sample of tab navigation code:

```html
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Pride Origins</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Whose House?</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Student Demographics</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">First Time In College (FTICs)</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">Faculty Demographics</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
      <h2 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Pride Origins </strong></h2>
      <hr/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="chart" id="trendUHln" style="width: 1150; height: 350;"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: need to redraw the chart after the tab is activated and visible -- where is the code to change tabs?

Comment: Thank you. I just added part of the tab code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, as mentioned in a comment above in reply to your post, is redraw the charts once a tab has been clicked.

The code below first grabs the nav element for the tabs via the `.nav-pills` class. We then set up a click event listener on the entire nav element itself. When a specific tab item is clicked, that event `e` is handled in the function (callback) declared with the event listener. The first thing we do is check to make sure that it was indeed one of the tab nav items clicked within the overall `nav` element. We do this by checking whether or not the tab item has an HTML attribute `data-toggle='tab'`. If it does, then we know that one of the tab nav items was clicked, and we then want to redraw/resize the charts.

```
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav-pills');
nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Event delegation - make sure it was one of the tab nav items that was clicked
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('a[data-toggle="tab"]')) {
        // Call the redraw function for the charts
    }
});
```